# Bash script stops executing unless typed "exit" in terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a small bash script with which I want to install all dependencies and programs for my project.

Problematic code:

```
#Part1
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
newgrp docker

#Part 2
git clone "https://github.com/GetDKAN/dkan-tools.git"
```

The function calls are correct, but I don't know why, but after finishing with, so-called part 1, the execution stops unless I type in the terminal "exit". I am not very familiar with bash and how everything works, but I feel like it is entering a session, and I need to exit it. But, it confuses me since if I type them one by one in the terminal, it will work perfectly.

Could someone tell me what is happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: You'll have to provide more information to be able to tell that.     

1) Are you really using "somegit.git", or is there in reality a full url or path there ? 
2) If you manually run the git command, does it do any interactive things ? (like ask you for a username or confirmation). 
3) Is the script running with the correct working directory set. 
4) When the script is "stuck" and you have to type exit, you should check (from another terminal if needbe) if the git process is running (`ps`). 
5) Is there no (log)output at all ? after the `newgrp` command.

Comment: @Raxi I have put the real code of "somegit.git". To answer your questions, there is no interaction like asking for a username... In the full version of the script I am executing a lot of commands all of them with terminal output, but they never stuck the rest of the execution. Only at this step that happens

Comment: And you're sure the `newgrp`  did finish successfully ? , if you add `id -a;` on the line above the `git clone`; does it output userinfo then before getting stuck ? and ifso, does that userinfo reflect your `newgrp docker`-changes ?

Comment: `bash -ex` `e` for exiting on error - a must for scripting but not the default .  `-x` for debug,  will output commands as they're being run.   Works in shebang also

Comment: @Raxi I have just checked with `id -a;` and yes the output corresponds to the previous commands ...

Comment: and no output from git at all after that?

Comment: `newgrp` starts a new shell, like when you type `bash`, only the process belongs to a different group. To exit the new process you have to type `exit`.

Comment: To execute commands in this new shell, I suggest to use a here-document.